# Getting: unknown directive "js_import" when njs used with Nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am making the following statement in the Nginx conf:

```
js_import http.js;
```

But it seems to give me `unknown directive "js_import"`

I have verified whether the njs is installed. I can seem to get into the cli. Version of njs is 0.3.9

The below statement seems to be working and is place`http` block:

```
js_include http.js
```

This also seem to work and is placed in the `server` block inside `http` block:

```
js_content hello
```

Nginx seems to be the latest version.

I cannot seems to find what I am missing here.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where have you placed the `js_import` statement? It is only permitted within the `http` or `stream` blocks.

Comment: I am placing in the http block.

Comment: I have the same problem, I copied and pasted the example from the doc. The load_module directive is there and the module file is present... (nginx 1.17.5 from docker)

Answer (score 4):

reading [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/njs/install.html) and putting

`load_module /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_js_module.so;`

at the top of my `nginx.conf` solved my problem you may need to put something like this

`load_module modules/ngx_http_js_module.so;`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have already mentioned the load_module modules/ngx_http_js_module.so; at the top. It is still not working. I have edited the question please check.

Comment: Yes I did. I tried with non existent paths to verify the same.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you are using the latest nginx version or ngx_http_js_module version js_import come with ngx_http_js_module v0.4.0 as stated in the documenttion http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_js_module.html#js_import